# React UploadCare Remove Button Should Return Null

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik, uploadcare

I wanted to make the value of imageUrl to be null if the remove button is click using `uploadcare/react-widget`. Right now, it doesn't set the value to null, it still returns the value of the original imageUrl. How do you call the function when you click the 'remove button'?

```
                    <Widget
                      tabs="file"
                      name="imageUrl"
                      clearable="true"
                      imagesOnly="true"
                      previewStep="true"
                      value={props.values.imageUrl}
                      onChange={upload =>
                        props.setFieldValue('imageUrl', upload.originalUrl)
                      }
                      publicKey={process.env.UPLOADCARE_KEY}
                    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onChange` callback fires only when a file is uploaded. If you need to handle this case, consider using `onFileSelect` instead. For example,

```
const Example = () => {
  return (
    <Widget
      publicKey={process.env.UPLOADCARE_KEY}
      previewStep
      clearable
      onFileSelect={file => {
        if (!file) {
          console.log("File removed from widget");
          return;
        }
        file.done(fileInfo => {
          console.log("File uploaded: ", fileInfo.cdnUrl);
        });
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Make sure to update `react-widget` to the latest version (1.3.7) to be able to use this method.

Basically, `onFileSelect` is a binding to the `onChange` [method](https://uploadcare.com/docs/file-uploader-api/widget/#widget-on-change) of the vanilla JS API of the widget.